# Геокодирование в Яндекс Картах

Tags: javascript, jquery, yandex-maps-api

Пришлось перейти на версию карт API 1.1 с 2.1, так как в Excel в WebBrowser стоит IE7. **Вопрос**:

Как получить координаты геокодирования по адресу? `this.get(0)` выдает не то, пример взят [отсюда](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/1.x/dg/concepts/geocoder-docpage/):

```js
        var map, geoResult;
        YMaps.jQuery(function () {
            map = new YMaps.Map(YMaps.jQuery("#YMapsID")[0]);
            map.setCenter(new YMaps.GeoPoint(37.64, 55.76), 10);
            map.addControl(new YMaps.TypeControl());
            var geocoder = new YMaps.Geocoder("Москва Арбат", {results: 1, boundedBy: map.getBounds()});
            YMaps.Events.observe(geocoder, geocoder.Events.Load, function () {
                geoResult = this.get(0);
                map.addOverlay(geoResult);
                map.setBounds(geoResult.getBounds());
            });
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>ТЕСТИМ!</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/1.1/index.xml" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">    
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="YMapsID" style="width:600px;height:400px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Координаты нужны, чтобы потом добавить [новую метку](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/1.x/dg/tasks/how-to-add-placemark-docpage/) с нужным мне описанием:

```
// Создает метку в центре Москвы
var placemark = new YMaps.Placemark(new YMaps.GeoPoint(КООРДИНАТЫ));
placemark.name = "Москва";
placemark.description = "Столица Российской Федерации";
map.addOverlay(placemark);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решает `this.get(0).getGeoPoint()`:

```
// Создает метку в центре Москвы
var placemark = new YMaps.Placemark(this.get(0).getGeoPoint());
placemark.name = "Москва";
placemark.description = "Столица Российской Федерации";
map.addOverlay(placemark);
```